# ModuleNotFoundError on psycopg2 only on compiled script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, atom-editor, psycopg2

I am currently working through a tutorial on database entry using psycopg2 but I can't seem to get my script to find it. Used pip install and my script is written in Atom. When I import psycopg2 in the command prompt it works fine but my Atom script wont run:

**ATOM SCRIPT**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:\\users\j.meiring\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages')
print(sys.path)
import psycopg2

def create_table():
    conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='database1' user='postgres' password='postgres123' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(item,quantity,price):
    conn=psycopg2.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO store VALUES (?,?,?)",(item,quantity,price))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn=psycopg2.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM store")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def delete(item):
    conn=psycopg2.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM store WHERE item=?",(item,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def update(quantity,price,item):
    conn=psycopg2.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE store SET quantity=?, price=? WHERE item=?",(quantity,price,item,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

create_table()
#print(view())
```

**CMD OUTPUT**

```
C:\Users\J.Meiring\Documents\Py\Database>script2.py
['C:\\Users\\J.Meiring\\Documents\\Py\\Database', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib\\site-packages', 'c:\\users\\j.meiring\x07ppdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\J.Meiring\Documents\Py\Database\script2.py", line 4, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

C:\Users\J.Meiring\Documents\Py\Database>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print("'c:\\users\j.meiring\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages' in sys.path")
'c:\users\j.meiringppdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages' in sys.path
>>> print('c:\\users\j.meiring\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages' in sys.path)
False
>>> sys.path.append('c:\\users\j.meiring\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages')
>>> print('c:\\users\j.meiring\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages' in sys.path)
True
>>> import psycopg2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are showing this in your code, adding a path to `sys.path`:

```
sys.path.append('c:\\users\j.meiring\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages')
```

Your error appears differently, however. I've added line breaks to the path it provides, for readability.

```
['C:\\Users\\J.Meiring\\Documents\\Py\\Database',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\users\\j.meiring\x07ppdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Note in the last line this part of the path...

```
'c:\\users\\j.meiring\x07ppdata\\local......
```

Here instead of `appdata` you see `x07ppdata`. That may be 0x07, or the BELL character (a control-character, not typically visible). It may be this character is some kind of unicode embed in your file and you haven't noticed because it looks correct when it is rendered? In any case, this `x07ppdata` directory does not exist, therefore that path doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I revised my path to use double back slashes as it was interpreting the \a as unicode. It now appears my install of psycopg2 might have an issue:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\J.Meiring\Documents\Py\Database\script2.py", line 4, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "c:\users\j.meiring\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg' `